# How to display the memory usage in GB instead of percent by htop in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, htop

Is there any way to get the RAM used by each process in GB rather than in % by `htop` in ubuntu?

Answer (score 11):

- Press `f2` to show setting
- In `Columns` menu, go to `Available Columns` and choose`M_RESIDENT`
- `F10` to save setting

Now we have a new column showing number of RAM used.

Answer (score 2):

You can gt memory information by showing column "M_RESIDENT" instead of "PERCENT_CPU"